# Laravel 5.1 Transform your PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm using laracasts/utilities for Transform your PHP to JavaScript. I have installed it through composer

**Composer**

```
"require": {
        "laracasts/utilities": "~2.0"
    }
```

Then i have added the provider in config/app.php

**app.php**

```
'providers' => [
    '...',
    'Laracasts\Utilities\JavaScript\JavaScriptServiceProvider'
];
```

In my project controller at the top i have use JavaScript

And this is how i using it

```
public function index()
{
    // Get all projects
    $projecten = Project::paginate(10);


    JavaScript::put([
        "total"        => $projecten->total(),
        "per_page"     => $projecten->perPage(),
        "current_page" => $projecten->currentPage(),
        "last_page"    => $projecten->lastPage()
    ]);

    return view('dashboard.admin.project', compact('projecten'));
}
```

Also i have configured this by using the command `php artisan vendor:publish`

and change the following in **javascript.php**

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View to Bind JavaScript Vars To
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Set this value to the name of the view (or partial) that
    | you want to prepend all JavaScript variables to.
    | This can be a single view, or an array of views.
    | Example: 'footer' or ['footer', 'bottom']
    |
    */
    'bind_js_vars_to_this_view' => 'dashboard.master.dashboard_master',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | JavaScript Namespace
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By default, we'll add variables to the global window object. However,
    | it's recommended that you change this to some namespace - anything.
    | That way, you can access vars, like "SomeNamespace.someVariable."
    |
    */
    'js_namespace' => 'pos'

];
```

The problem is i have set bind_js_vars_to_this_view to dashboard.master.dashboard_master this is my master page for the dashboard. If i look in the html it works::

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>window.pos = window.pos || {};pos.total = 75;pos.per_page = 10;pos.current_page = 1;pos.last_page = 8;</script>


            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
                <title>POS</title>
            <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://pos.dev:8000/css/bootstrap.css">
```

But is stores the js variables at the top. And also my style sheets arent working properly after using this approuch.

How could i use the js variables below on this page. I think this also solve the problem with css BUT HOW???

Comment: Can you inlcude the top part of your dashboard_master view? Cause I do the exact same thing in my application and I also get the variables on top of the page but i'm not experiencing any problems with it. The strange thing is in your html page you get the <script> part below the <head>. I get the <script> part completly on top of my page even above the <html> tags.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console showing problems with loading your CSS files?